# using jquery to get dom elements name

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to retrieve a elements name as a string that is also cross browser compatible.

for example I have an event that I look at the target and I want to just get the name of it. So for example I click on a a tag and the eventListener returns the event.

```
myEventListener: function(event){
  strName = event.target
}
```

The above gives me the target but what I want is just a value of the name of the a tag. 
so an a tag would give me a string result of "a"
so something like this pseudo code.

```
 myEventListener: function(event){
  strName = event.target.name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pseudocode should work just fine! A `name` property is exposed on `a` elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name by using

$(event.target).attr("name")

Comment: This returns undefined from my live event

Comment: if it returned undefined this means that the element you are checking has no name attribute.